# TinyMCE adding code/pre to toolbar/shortcuts

Tags: tinymce

Using TinyMCE, is it possible to add toolbar buttons or shortcuts for `<code>` and `<pre>` formatting (so that they work in the same way as `<b>`, `<i>` etc)?

Having to go through 4 clicks to get to `code` (Format -> Formats -> Inline -> Code) and another 4 clicks to get to `pre` (Format -> Formats -> Blocks -> Pre) is a massive pain.

Adding the keyword `code` to the list of toolbar buttons or even to the Format menu results in the **source code** button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the TinyMCE initialization:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 500,
  toolbar: 'codeSC',
  [...]

  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.addButton('codeSC', {
      text: '<code>',
      icon: false,
      onclick: function () {
        editor.insertContent('<code>Text inside code</code>');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

codeSC = codeShortCut

Comment: Excellent - thanks... that definitely gives me a good starting point.  For shortcuts, see [this blog from TinyMCE](https://go.tinymce.com/blog/creating-keyboard-shortcuts-tinymce/?_ga=2.19036408.1797749624.1523546646-1266258961.1523546646)